# How to split strings based on "/n" in Java

Tags: java, string

I have got a string

```
$key1={331015EA261D38A7}
$key2={9145A98BA37617DE}
$key3={EF745F23AA67243D}
```

How do i split each of the keys based on "$" and the "next line" element? 
and then place it in an Arraylist?

The output should look like this:
Arraylist[0]:

```
$key1={331015EA261D38A7}
```

Arraylist[1]:

```
$key2={9145A98BA37617DE}
```

Arraylist[2]:

```
$key3={EF745F23AA67243D}
```

Comment: Can you share the output you're trying to get for this sample? It would make the question much clearer.

Comment: str.split("\n")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: By `Arraylist` you mean actual instance of ArrayList (like `ArrayList<String> lines = ..;  //rest of code which fills that list`), or simple array of Strings `String[] lines = ...`?

Comment: I think you mean `\n` not `/n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't split, *search* your `String` for key value pairs:

```
\$(?<key>[^=]++)=\{(?<value>[^}]++)\}
```

For example:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(?<key>[^=]++)=\\{(?<value>[^}]++)\\}");
final String input = "$key1={331015EA261D38A7}\n$key2={9145A98BA37617DE}\n$key3={EF745F23AA67243D}";
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
final Map<String, String> parse = new HashMap<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    parse.put(matcher.group("key"), matcher.group("value"));
}
//print values
parse.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("Key '%s' has value '%s'%n", k, v));
```

Output:

> Key 'key1' has value '331015EA261D38A7'
>   Key 'key2' has value '9145A98BA37617DE'
>   Key 'key3' has value 'EF745F23AA67243D'

Comment: Yes. You are the saviour xD

Comment: Boris, how do i change the regex so that $key1="331015EA261D38A7" format can also be filter by the regex?

Comment: @Shawn replace the curly brackets with quotes. Or get rid of them altogether and strip off whatever characters need to be removed afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to split by new line, it is as simple as :

```
yourstring.split("\n"):
```

Answer (score 0):

yourstring.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

Comment: This will work only if text uses same line separator in defined in system, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, right. but also its system independent

Comment: @SimonLudwig I think you misunderstand. If you are parsing a file, it has the linebreaks it has. The system is irrelevant. Using the system line separator is not the right choice; avoiding the line separator entirely is.

Comment: "but also its system independent" quite opposite. Value of `System.getProperty("line.separator")` depends **only** on system. For instance if I create file on Linux where lines are separated with `\n` and will try to split it on Windows which is using `\r\n` then your solution can't work since `\r\n` will not match `\n`. If you are looking for independent solution than you can try with `\r?\n|\r` (since `split` is using regex).